# How to shorten the declaration of variable in a class?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am working with some API service that throw back a not properly formatted JSON. I wonder if there is a way to shorten the declaration in my Flutter model class.

So to illustrate the problem , I am getting back the JSON in the following format.

```
"right_eye_eyelid":{
    "right_eye_eyelid_0": {"y": 0, "x": 0},
    "right_eye_eyelid_1": {"y": 0, "x": 0},
    ......
    ......
    "right_eye_eyelid_61": {"y": 0, "x": 0},
    "right_eye_eyelid_62": {"y": 0, "x": 0},
}
```

For model class in my flutter is a bit massive like

```
class LandmarkCoordinate{
  int x;
  int y;
}

class RightEyeEyelid{
  LandmarkCoordinate right_eye_eyelid_0;
  LandmarkCoordinate right_eye_eyelid_1;
  LandmarkCoordinate right_eye_eyelid_2;
  LandmarkCoordinate right_eye_eyelid_4;
  ... ...
  LandmarkCoordinate right_eye_eyelid_60;
  LandmarkCoordinate right_eye_eyelid_61;
}
```

Because the **field naming is in a ascending and predictable format**.Is there a way to **shorten the declaration of the variable**? Instead of manual typing out all the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"properly formatted" is subjective.

In general, don't put `N` variables.

#### Option 1:

Use a generic map. Remember when parsing JSON, a class/object is just a concretely defined Map; the field are still all strings.

```
class FaceLandmark{
  Map<String, LandmarkCoordinate> right_eye_eyelid = new HashMap();
}
```

Then you can do `right_eye_eyelid.get("right_eye_eyelid_" + index)`

---

#### Option 2:

(if you can change or just parse the API response manually)

Use a [`List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/List-class.html)...

```
class FaceLandmark{
  List<LandmarkCoordinate> right_eye_eyelid = new List(62);
}
```

Similarly, rewrite your JSON

```
{ ...
    "right_eye_eyelid": [
        {"y": 0, "x": 0},
        {"y": 0, "x": 0},
        ......
        {"y": 0, "x": 0}
    ]
}
```

Comment: but the api is not returning a list , they are returning field like right_eye_eyelid_0 , right_eye_eyelid_1

Comment: Do you have access to change the API response? If not, use a `HashMap<String, LandmarkCoordinate>`

Comment: no , I do not have the control over the API , these are external API service.